# Return Async List of objects as Json MVC + Knockout

Tags: c#, json, asynchronous, knockout.js

The following code is part of a regular controller (not using API), I need to return multiple values to a knockout.js file. The problem is, the file is waiting to receive Json, when I send the list, I get a message saying "SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0", but if I change the signature and convert the objects to JSON, then the linq for async doesn't run.

**My question is, how can I get the list using async (so it work in knockout) and still send it as JSON? or what way should I go?**

```
public async Task<List<InsDetDTO>> LoadInsDet(int id)
    {
        var ins = await db.INSPECTIONDETAILS
            .Select(t =>
            new InsDetDTO()
            {
                Id = t.ID,
                AreaEquipment = t.AreaEquipment,
                InspectionID = t.InspectionID
            }).Where(t => t.InspectionID == id).ToListAsync();
        return ins;
    }
```

Side note, this is the first time I try using knockout, any information is appreciated, and yes I already googled this for a while.

**KO**

```
var ViewModel = function () {
var self = this;
//inspection
self.inspections = ko.observableArray();
self.error = ko.observable();

//details
self.detail = ko.observableArray();

var inspUri = '/INSPECTIONs/LoadIns';
var insDetUri = '/INSPECTIONs/LoadInsDet/';

//function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
    self.error(''); // Clear error message
    return $.ajax({
        type: method,
        //url: uri,
        url: uri,
        //async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        self.error(errorThrown);
    });
}

function getAllInspections() {
    ajaxHelper(inspUri, 'GET').done(function (data) {
        self.inspections(data);
    });
}

self.getInspectionDetails = function (item) {
    ajaxHelper(insDetUri + item.Id, 'GET').done(function (data) {
        self.detail(data);
    });
}

// Fetch the initial data.
getAllInspections();
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

**View**
    
            
                
            
        
        
            
                
                    
                        Inspections

Details

```
        <!-- ko if:detail() -->

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h2 class="panel-title">Detail</h2>
                </div>
                <table class="table">
                    <tr><td>AreaEquipment</td><td data-bind="text: detail().AreaEquipment"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>InspectionID</td><td data-bind="text: detail().InspectionID"></td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: What I would do is put the url to the action method in the adress bar of the browser, preferably chrome because it will show the json without forcing you to save it, and see what it returns. Then analyze the return.

Comment: I get [{"Id":2,"InspectionID":12,"AreaEquipment":"f                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "}]  which is ok, problem is that it is not async

Comment: It is async. What is KO expecting: an array? Because that's an array.

Comment: I added the app.js (ko) and the view

Comment: What is the return type of your controller method? Is it returning a JsonResult? It looks like the data you're getting is JS not JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing a little bit, I found my problem, in the controller, if I change the results to a List first, then when I convert to JSON it's easier to catch them on the view, these are my changes, hopefully this will help someone.

**View** Notice that click: $parent.getInspectionDetails populates the details in KO code, so then I can use foreach for all the details

```
<div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h2 class="panel-title">Inspections</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled" data-bind="foreach: inspections">
                        <li>
                            <strong><span data-bind="text: Id"></span></strong>
                            <span data-bind="text: date"></span>
                            <strong><span data-bind="text: labDesc"></span></strong>
                            <span data-bind="text: username"></span>
                            <small><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.getInspectionDetails">Details</a></small>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" data-bind="visible: error"><p data-bind="text: error"></p></div>
        </div>
<!-- ko if:detail() -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h2 class="panel-title">Detail</h2>
                </div>
                <table class="table">
                    <tr class="list-unstyled" data-bind="foreach: detail">
                        <td>AreaEquipment</td><td data-bind="text: AreaEquip"></td>
                        <td>InspectionID</td><td data-bind="text: Inspectionid"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Controller** (note the ToList())

```
public JsonResult LoadInsDet(int id)
    {
        var ins = from t in db.INSPECTIONDETAILS.Where(t=>t.InspectionID==id).ToList()
                  //where t.InspectionID == id 
                  select new InsDetDTO()
                  {
                      Id = t.ID,
                      AreaEquip = t.AreaEquipment,
                      Inspectionid = t.InspectionID
                  };
        return Json(ins, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```